# want to calculate rannor(-1) equalent value in R

Tags: r

hi I am trying to converrt SAS code in R. I had problem in this,
my SAS code is as below

```
%let de=%str(dev[3] (0,0,0));

data test;

array &dev ;

do i=1 to 3;

     dev[i]=rannor(-1);
end;

run;
```

while iam using **rnorm(-1)** to calculate the random normal variate for N[0,1]
it was showing an error message like **invalid argument**.
can You please help me in this.

Comment: See `?rnorm`  The first argument is the number of samples desired.  So -1 doesn't make sense.  Maybe you want `rnorm(1)`.

Comment: in SAS, `rannor` takes as first argument the `seed`. So you could use `set.seed(-1)` (or any other integer value) in R before doing your randomization.